# Setting up Django on IIS

Tags: python, django, windows, iis, iis-7

I have been trying to setup Django to work on IIS 7 Enterprise (Version 6.1 on Windows 7), but so far have been unable to.  I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 2.7.  I am using PyISAPI to run Django on IIS.  I have tried both the 2.6 version of PyISAPI and the 2.7 version (http://blog.wolfplusplus.com/?attachment_id=276).  I have followed the following tutorials:

[IIS Not Linking to Django with PyISAPIe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2640066/iis-not-linking-to-django-with-pyisapie)

http://blog.wolfplusplus.com/?p=272

I have followed others also, and all of them do slightly different things.  None of them have worked with me so far, and all of the tutorials seems to be a couple of years old.  Can someone provide a straightforward up to date guide on how to setup Django 1.8 (running with Python 2.7) with IIS.  There seems to be multiple approaches such as using FastCGI, but I have read that PyISAPI is much faster than FastCGI.  My goal is to run a Django application on IIS.

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Have you tried mod_wsgi? https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationOnWindows

Comment: This seems like it is for Apache and not IIS.

Answer (score 6):

I've just followed [that](http://chrisberragan.com/posts/2014/03/19/installing-django-on-iis-7-5/) guide with following corrections:

1. You should give permission on the site folder to App Pool's identity. I just went to App Pool's Advanced Settings > Process model > Identity and set it to local admin account for testing purposes.
2. Correct environment variable name in step 4.13 is `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`, underscores were eaten by markup

and everything worked fine! If it's not applicable in your case please provide some additional details.